# How to set default environment variables for other users?

Tags: lubuntu, sudo, environment-variables, bashrc

I installed postgres under Lubuntu 13.04. When I try to run it:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

it gives me this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I can start it changing the port:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
export PGPORT=5433
psql
```

but I would to make it the default port. I tried to add `export PGPORT=5433` to the .bashrc of postgres user, but it doesn't work; it seems that .bashrc is not executed with `sudo -u`, since if I do:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
. .bashrc
psql
```

it works.

Is there a way to make `sudo -u USER -i` execute .bashrc, or is there another way to make the change of that environment variable permanent for postgres user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sudoers(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) man page has a "Command Environment" section that reads, in part:

> On Linux and AIX systems the contents of **/etc/environment** are also
>          included.

Comment: Thank you all, glenn and @KunalSangwan. I' ve found also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables and it seems that .bashrc, .bash_profile and /etc/profile are deprecated for setting env. vars in ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

for a single user : Login to your account and open .bash_profile file
$ vi ~/.bash_profile

for all user(s) : You need to setup global config in /etc/profile OR /etc/bash.bashrc file for all users:

## vi /etc/profile

hope that helps.